# Warning in scipy multivariate_normal covariance specification

Tags: python, scipy

My code seems to work, let's start from there, but I passed by working on colab to work locally using Visual Studio Code and some warnings arised.

Specifically I have the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, multivariate_normal
...
std_last_layer = math.sqrt((kernel_layers_in_x_alpha[-1].nngp)[0][0])
x_list = np.linspace(-3*std_last_layer, 3*std_last_layer, 50)
var_last_layer = float(std_last_layer ** 2)
rootKey, keys = split_keys(rootKey, 1) 

y_true_dict = []
for x1 in x_list:
  for x2 in x_list:
    y_true_dict.append(multivariate_normal.cdf((x1, x2), [0, 0], [[var_last_layer, 0], [0, var_last_layer]]))
```

And I get the following warning:

```
Argument of type "list[list[Unknown]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "cov" of type "int" in function "cdf"
  "list[list[Unknown]]" is incompatible with "int"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

What's wrong with the code I produced? From the [documentation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L287-L782) the function multivariate_normal.cdf should accept an array_like as vector of means and an array_like as covariance matrix.